# MS Access treats my column/alias as a parameter... But only sometimes

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, alias

New to SQL but I'm fairly sure that my query is correct. I've tried it a thousand different ways but it will still sometimes treat my column/alias lead_ID_t as a parameter. I've put square brackets around everything to try to help but to no avail...

I'm editing the query in notepad++, and when I paste it into Access, it runs just fine. Then I save and close the query. When I try to run it again, it treats lead_ID_t as a parameter and my formatting is completely gone... Can anyone explain what is happening?

```
SELECT [Total].[lead_ID_t] AS [Lead ID], 

IIF(isnull([Total].[lead_count_t]-[F9].[lead_count_f]),0,[Total].[lead_count_t]-[F9].[lead_count_f]) AS [V Calls]

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Lead_ID] AS [lead_ID_t], Count([Lead_ID]) AS [lead_count_t] 

FROM (SELECT * FROM [Logs] WHERE [log_actor] <> "Five9 Dialer") As [TData] GROUP BY [Lead_ID])  AS [Total] 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Lead_ID] AS [Lead_ID_f], count([Lead_ID]) AS [lead_count_f] 

FROM (SELECT * FROM [Logs] WHERE [log_actor] = "Five9 Dialer") As [FData] GROUP BY [Lead_ID])  AS [F9] ON [Total].[lead_ID_t]=[F9].[lead_ID_f];
```

ps. same error occurs with and without the iif statement

Comment: What does this mean *it treats lead_ID_t as a parameter*? Does it prompt you to enter parameter? And MS Access neither saves query format or pretty prints it!

Comment: @Parfait Yes, that's what I mean. And that's really unfortunate... Makes editing long queries near impossible in the application. :(

Comment: It will pop up asking for a value for any column in the SELECT list that it doesn't recognise. So for some reason it is not recognising the column name. That column name is coming from a sub-query. Perhaps not a proper answer to the question (which might be a bug) - could you move the sub-query to another query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an adjusted, compact query:

1. Remove redundant nested levels as you can use `WHERE` in an aggregate `GROUP BY` query.
2. Remove `DISTINCT` as aggregate queries already return distinct grouping values.
3. Replace `IIF()` (statement that returns zero for `NULL`) for `NZ()`.
4. While *Total* may not be a listed MS Access or JET reserved word, it might be a GUI application reserved word and thereby causing issues. Use previous subquery aliases, *TData* and *FData*.
5. Alternatively, use conditional aggregation for one main query without subqueries or joins and where you can use calculated columns to avoid repetition.

Compact query

```
SELECT [TData].[lead_ID_t] AS [Lead ID],
       NZ(([TData].[lead_count_t] - [FData].[lead_count_f]),0) AS [V Calls]
FROM
  (SELECT [Lead_ID] AS [lead_ID_t],
          COUNT([Lead_ID]) AS [lead_count_t]
   FROM [Logs]
   WHERE [log_actor] <> 'Five9 Dialer'
   GROUP BY [Lead_ID]) AS [TData]

LEFT JOIN    
  (SELECT [Lead_ID] AS [Lead_ID_f],
          COUNT([Lead_ID]) AS [lead_count_f]
   FROM [Logs]
   WHERE [log_actor] = 'Five9 Dialer' 
   GROUP BY [Lead_ID]) AS [FData]

ON [TData].[lead_ID_t] = [FData].[lead_ID_f];
```

Conditional aggregation

```
SELECT l.[Lead ID],
       SUM(IIF(l.[log_actor] <> 'Five9 Dialer', 1, 0)) AS [lead_count_t],
       SUM(IIF(l.[log_actor] = 'Five9 Dialer', 1, 0)) AS [lead_count_f],
       NZ(([lead_count_t] - [lead_count_f]),0) AS [V Calls]
FROM [Logs] l
GROUP BY l.[Lead_ID]
```

Comment: Worked like a gem, didn't think I could use conditional aggregation, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!